# Run time error 91 on range missing value check

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to check if a cell value occurs within two ranges and, if it does, to place that same value into a third cell. I'm using a sudoku-like puzzle to test the code. When I get to the point of checking whether the value "3' occurs in the ranges I receive a run-time error 91 code in the first "if" statement. Any help appreciated.

The test data looks like this, starting in "D26":

```
1   4       9   6   3   5   2   8
2       8   1   7   4   3   6   9
    6   9   2   5   8   1   4   7
1   4       9   6   3   5   2   8
2       8   1   7   4   3   6   9
    6   9   2   5   8   1   4   7
1   4       9   6   3   5   2   8
2       8   1   7   4   3   6   9
    6   9   2   5   8   1   4   7
```

and the relevant code:

```
For r = 26 To 34
    For a = 1 To 9


        Set row1 = Range(Cells(r, 4), Cells(r, 12)).Find(What:=a)
        Set row2 = Range(Cells(r + 1, 4), Cells(r + 1, 12)).Find(What:=a)
        Set row3 = Range(Cells(r + 2, 4), Cells(r + 2, 12)).Find(What:=a)


        If row1 = a And row3 = a And row2 Is Nothing Then

            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(r + 1, 4), Cells(r + 1, 6))) = 2 Then
                nextfree = Range(Cells(r + 1, 4), Cells(r + 1, 6)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Column
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 1, nextfree).Value = a
            End If

        ElseIf row1 = a And row2 = a And row3 Is Nothing Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(r + 2, 4), Cells(r + 2, 6))) = 2 Then
                nextfree = Range(Cells(r + 2, 4), Cells(r + 2, 6)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Column
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 2, nextfree).Value = a
            End If

        ElseIf row2 = a And row3 = a And row3 Is Nothing Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(r + 2, 4), Cells(r + 2, 6))) = 2 Then
                nextfree = Range(Cells(r + 2, 4), Cells(r + 2, 6)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Column
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 2, nextfree).Value = a
            End If

        End If

    Next a
    r = r + 2
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to check your logic and declare all your variables and put Option Explicit at the top of your code. The first logic bit pertains to this line: If row1 = a And row3 = a And row2 Is Nothing Then... If row1 or row3 is nothing (i.e. a wasn't found) then it will fail as you cannot do If nothing = a . But even fixing that I am not certain the logic is correct to solve. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look again. What's odd is the code worked fine if I try to solve for one number, it only fails when I get it to loop from 1 through 9 but I'll look for an alternative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is that `Find` returns a `Range`, but if the search term is not found, the method returns `Nothing`.

The first `If` tests `row3 = a`, but in Row 3 of your test data, the number 3 is not present. So the Range object `row3` is `Nothing`. Since it's Nothing, the test is not valid.

(Note that the test is misleading, since you're not really testing the `Range` - the code is testing the `Range.Value`. But VBA is masking that, `Value` being the default property, which is why the logic of the error may not be clear at first glance.)

The following code assigns a *value* to three additional variables and the `If` statements test the **values**:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim row1 As Range, row2 As Range, row3 As Range
    Dim Val1 As Long, val2 As Long, val3 As Long
    Dim nextFree As Long

    For r = 26 To 34
        For a = 1 To 9       
            Set row1 = Range(Cells(r, 4), Cells(r, 12)).Find(What:=a)
            If row1 Is Nothing Then Val1 = 0 Else Val1 = row1.Value
            Set row2 = Range(Cells(r + 1, 4), Cells(r + 1, 12)).Find(What:=a)
            If row2 Is Nothing Then val2 = 0 Else val2 = row2.Value
            Set row3 = Range(Cells(r + 2, 4), Cells(r + 2, 12)).Find(What:=a)
            If row3 Is Nothing Then val3 = 0 Else val3 = row3.Value

            If Val1 = a And val3 = a And val2 = 0 Then

                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(r + 1, 4), Cells(r + 1, 6))) = 2 Then
                    nextFree = Range(Cells(r + 1, 4), Cells(r + 1, 6)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Column
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 1, nextFree).Value = a
                End If

            ElseIf Val1 = a And val2 = a And val3 = 0 Then
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(r + 2, 4), Cells(r + 2, 6))) = 2 Then
                    nextFree = Range(Cells(r + 2, 4), Cells(r + 2, 6)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Column
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 2, nextFree).Value = a
                End If

            ElseIf val2 = a And val3 = a And Val1 = 0 Then
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(r + 2, 4), Cells(r + 2, 6))) = 2 Then
                    nextFree = Range(Cells(r + 2, 4), Cells(r + 2, 6)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Column
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r + 2, nextFree).Value = a
                End If

            End If

        Next a
        r = r + 2
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! need to sort out a bit of my other logic but .find components make sense, appreciate the help